# Shell script issue with directory and filenames containing spaces

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I understand that one technique for dealing with spaces in filenames is to enclose the file name with single quotes: `"'"`.I have a directory and a filename with space. I want a shell script to read all the files along with the posted time and directory name. I wrote the below script:

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT_DATE=`date +'%d%m%Y'`
Temp_Path=/appinfprd/bi/infogix/IA83/InfogixClient/Scripts/IRP/
find /bishare/IRP_PROJECT/SFTP/  -type f | xargs ls -al > $Temp_Path/File_Posted_$CURRENT_DATE.txt
```

which is partially working. It is not working for the directory and files that has a space in it.

Comment: If you want a string with spaces to appear as a single token, just put it in double quotes.  For instance, `"$Temp_Path/File_Posted_$CURRENT_DATE.txt"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find -print0 | xargs -0` to reliably handle file names with special characters in them, including spaces and newlines.

```
find /bishare/IRP_PROJECT/SFTP/ -type f -print0 |
    xargs -0 ls -al > "$Temp_Path/File_Posted_$CURRENT_DATE.txt"
```

Alternatively, you can use `find -exec` which runs the command of your choice on every file found.

```
find /bishare/IRP_PROJECT/SFTP/ -type f -exec ls -al {} + \
    > "$Temp_Path/File_Posted_$CURRENT_DATE.txt"
```

In the specific case of `ls -l` you could take this one step further and use the `-ls` action.

```
find /bishare/IRP_PROJECT/SFTP/ -type f -ls > "$Temp_Path/File_Posted_$CURRENT_DATE.txt"
```

You should also get in the habit of quoting all variable expansions like you mentioned in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the IFS variable for a moment ([Internal Fields Separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator)):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Backing up the old value of IFS
OLDIFS="$IFS"
# Making newline the only field separator - spaces are no longer separators
# NOTE that " is the last character in line and the next line starts with "
IFS="
"
CURRENT_DATE=`date +'%d%m%Y'`
Temp_Path=/appinfprd/bi/infogix/IA83/InfogixClient/Scripts/IRP/
find /bishare/IRP_PROJECT/SFTP/  -type f | xargs ls -al > $Temp_Path/File_Posted_$CURRENT_DATE.txt
# Restore the original value of IFS
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```